# Disappearing Checkbox HTML label

Tags: html, css, checkbox, web, label

If you load this site and go to the upload tab on the side, you will see the checkbox button. When you click on this it disappears. clicking again anywhere on the website will make it reappear though.

As I don't know were the problem i,s I cant upload the code for the whole of my site here, so below is the whole site in a zip:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ef03jgg3vf8r1i6/AADhHtiUDw5YjPGrezMQxykza?dl=0

Or inspect see the code at:

http://www.brunel.ac.uk/~cs13lld/BadNoise/

Another small problem is the the input fields and the submit button are all set too width 100% of the div they are in but you can see that the input fields are clearly longer to the right of the submit button.

The website is half done so don't worry if things are missing.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove this rule or change it to `input[type='text']`:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus, button:focus {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome! yes that worked. any idea as to why the input and submit fields are both 100% but the input fields are going further out than the submit button?

Answer (score 1):

So my guess is that you're looking at this in chrome.

There's a bit of CSS on your style sheet that's causing the problem:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px)
input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus, button:focus {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

just remove the -webkit-appearance: none; and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, It did work but you got beat to the bat by someone else there! Any idea as to why the input and submit fields are both 100% but the input fields are going further out than the submit button?

Comment: Figured it out!             box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;